# Complex (Curly) Syntax PHP

Tags: php, curly-braces

Afternoon guys!

For some reason Complex (Curly) Syntax in my PHP code doesn't interpreter as variable

```
function view($name, $data = [])
{
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/views/{$name}.view.php';
}
```

Here is the code I am calling view('index'); the problem is I get this error:

```
Warning: require(./core/../app/views/{$name}.view.php): failed to open stream
```

By the way my PHP version before anyone asks is 7.0.13

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string has to be placed in double quotes (") instead of single quotes ('). Otherwise variables won't be replaced.

Look here:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.